# How to create table with complex header in flutter like this image?

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a table like this image but I don't know how to create a table with a complex header like this with flutter
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyy7c.png

Comment: Image is missing. Please add first

Comment: @JahidulIslam thanks, I was added image

Answer (score -1):

There is a package made for this: [flutter staggered grid view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)